# What statistic to use to measure effectiveness of treatment on fluctuating process

Tags: time-series, markov-process, markov-chain, extreme-value

I have a process $R$ that normally does something like a random walk between 0 and 1.  I have a set of treatments.  I believe that some of the treatments will bias the process $R$ in such a way that, after a "burn-in" period in which there's a bit of wandering, $R$ will take on higher values and eventually remain above 0.90 or 0.95 most of the time.  It may be that the process will sometimes drop down below 0.90 for a while, and wander, but it should come back to 0.95 again and stay there for a long time again.  I would like to measure this property--to show that for some treatments, $R$ remains at a high value most of time.

Does this make sense?  What are some useful concepts and statistics for this purpose?  *Mean sojourn time* for a Markov chain?  *Exceedences* from from extreme value theory?  Both seem to apply, in principle, but I'm not sure whether the mathematical frameworks in which they're embedded are what would be most appropriate given what I wrote above.  Something else?

I hope this isn't too vague.  I'm trying to get a sense of what to study further.

(Optional additional information: The data is from agent-based simulations in which agents imperfectly copy values of a variable $A \in [0,1]$ from each other.  For each agent at each timestep, there is a sample of agents that it's allowed to copy, and the agent copies the value from that agent among its sample that has the highest value of a variable $S$ representing success.  Agents with values of $A$ near 1 are more likely to be successful under certain conditions, though not others.  I expect that some treatments will produce distributions of $A$ among all agents with a mean near 1 most of the time, and small variance.  In others, the mean of $A$ will engage in more of a random walk with large variances.  So $R$ could be the mean value of $A$ in the entire population--although I'm open to suggestions that I should use some more sensitive measure.)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any special statistics for treating this sort of problem. But why not start simple? What if you measure the mean percentage of time spent above a certain threshold (like 0.90)? That should be enough to capture the effect you suspect some of the treatments would have.

Comment: Thanks.  That seems fine to me. I was worried that something like that might seem like an ad hoc measure that I had cooked up.  Conceptualizing what I'm doing in terms of existing concepts could also have the benefit of making available known mathematical methods--assuming I'm not applying known concepts and methods inappropriately, of course.  It sounds like there might not be any relevant literature.  But why not?  The type of effect I want to study seems like it would have come up many times before.  Perhaps naively, I worry that I'm misunderstanding something fundamental.